# Receiving a fatal error related to an extension that was removed

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, audit-trail, audit-logging

I removed the entire extension. This error showed up. I even replaced the entire application files. It still showed up. I searched AuditFieldBehavior, nothing showed up. Any ideas where I can look next?

AuditFieldBehavior is the class that extends CActiveRecordBehavior.

Here is the error:

> Fatal error: CComponent::__isset(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "AuditFieldBehavior" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition

[edit]
All my pages show blank. So I ran `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` and this is what I got:
[image]

in CWebLogRoute i get this last few lines:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have not reconfigured the behaviours of your models ( CActiveRecord) not to call on AuditFieldBehavior
Your models where you configured audit trails should have a similar function

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return array(
            'AuditFieldBehavior' => array(
                // Path to AuditFieldBehavior class.
                'class' => 'audit.components.AuditFieldBehavior',

                // Set to false if you just want to use getDbAttribute and other methods in this class.
                // If left unset the value will come from AuditModule::enableAuditField
                'enableAuditField' => null,

                // Any additional models you want to use to write model and model_id audits to.  If this array is not empty then
                // each field modifed will result in an AuditField being created for each additionalAuditModels.
                'additionalAuditModels' => array(
                    'Post' => 'post_id',
                ),

                // A list of values that will be treated as if they were null.
                'ignoreValues' => array('0', '0.0', '0.00', '0.000', '0.0000', '0.00000', '0.000000', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

Remove them and you should be fine

Note: You have to modify your config files as well

You may need remove the errorHandler, and LogRoute arrays in your config file to fully remove this

Comment: That is already removed. Config files are also removed. In fact, I replaced everything with my older files and I still get this error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the stack trace; we can find where it is being called from

Comment: okay, i realized this is only happening on chrome. Guess this would be another issue. Thanks for your help.